# Send output of dependency:display-ancestors to a file

Tags: maven

According to the [documentation for the maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/display-ancestors-mojo.html), the goal "display-ancestors" does not support any parameters.

Is there a way to send the output of that goal to a file?

I'm looking for something that can send just the output of this one goal to a file. E.g. the "list" goal of the same plugin, supports an "outputFile" parameter.

Or if there's some other way to get the parent pom's details during the build, and write it to a file... that would work too.

I tried using the `includeParents` option on the `dependency:list` goal, but that tries to get parents for all and breaks down when some JARs in our remote repo do not have a POM.

Comment: Redirecting the output stream?

Comment: @JFMeier : I'd like to do this only for that single plugin's output though.